# Panel, when added to the control for display, the size of the components increase

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am fairly new to c#, i had created the form with buttons on the panel. Then, i tried to add it to the control for display by calling its instance in another form class, everything looks bigger than expected. Is there any way, to keep the size as it is or is editing the elements dynamically the only way. Any help would be very kind.

Comment: Try  FlowLayoutPanel to add control to display, width and height adjust automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 approaches by which you can manage the above issue : 
1.Progrmatically handle the position ,and size of controls thorugh code .

For example : 
Locate the Form1_Load event procedure, and add the following code to the procedure to customize the appearance of the Form control:
    //Set up the form.
    this.MaximizeBox = false;
    this.MinimizeBox = false;
    this.BackColor = Color.White;
    this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(155, 265);
    this.Text = "Run-time Controls";
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

For clear understanding visit this link : 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319266/how-to-programmatically-add-controls-to-windows-forms-at-run-time-by-u

2.Second approach is as suggested in comments use FlowLayoutPanel :

The FlowLayoutPanel control is a container control that provides dynamically layout for the child controls that can be arranged horizontally or vertically. The flow direction of the control sets the direction of arrangements of controls.

For better understanding please visit this link :

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/flowlayoutpanel-in-C-Sharp/